# Roles do not work when logging into Laravel

Tags: laravel

I come to tell you about a situation that I cannot solve, I don't know why it happens.
I have an app in which there are 4 roles,

1. admin = users table
2. empresa = users table
3. cliente = clientes table
4. cajero = cajeros table

   ```
    use the login given by laravel 
   composer require laravel/ui
   php artisan ui vue --auth
   ```

Well, the problem comes when I try to log in with roles such as cliente or cajero, the admin and empresa role does not cause conflicts since being in the table that is automatically created by the same Laravel application (users), it does not cause conflicts.
here I describe the problem

For example, I enter with a cajero, if I enter the cajero and send the route /cajero, it works well, but if I delete the route it asks me to log in again, not like with the admin and empresa users, if I log in with any of them and it sends me to the route /dashboard for example, everything works fine and if I delete the route I get a message since in the login view I put a guest that detects whether or not the session is started

```
@guest
 
            <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                {{ __('Cerrar sesión') }}
            </a>

            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                @csrf
            </form>
       
 

@endguest
```

I have a middleware that does the starting function depending on where it comes from

```
     public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');

       
        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            return $this->configurarGuardia('web', 'users', $request, $next);
        }

         
        if (Auth::guard('cliente')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            return $this->configurarGuardia('cliente', 'clientes', $request, $next);
        }
 
        if (Auth::guard('cajero')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            return $this->configurarGuardia('cajero', 'cajeros', $request, $next);
        }

       
        return $this->configurarGuardia('web', 'users', $request, $next);
    }

    protected function configurarGuardia($guardia, $contraseñas, $request, $next)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Auth::shouldUse($guardia);
        config(['auth.defaults.guard' => $guardia]);
        config(['auth.defaults.passwords' => $contraseñas]);

        return $next($request);
    }


atuh.php

    // config/auth.php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'cliente' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clientes',
        ],

        'cajero' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'cajeros',
        ],
    ],
 

     'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'clientes' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Cliente::class,
    ],

    'cajeros' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Cajero::class,
    ],
    ],


admin and empresa routes

        Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->group(function () {    //routes});
        Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:empresa'])->group(function () {    //routes});

cliente and cajero

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:cliente']], function () { //routes});
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:cajero']], function () { //routes});
```

If you can see the syntax of both routes they are different, since if I use the syntax of the admin and empresa routes in cliente and cajero it does not work

NOT WORK

```
 Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:cliente'])->group(function () {    //routes});

     Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:cajero'])->group(function () {    //routes});
```

in tables I use a role_id field to see their role

```
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('cajeros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(4);
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        }); 
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(2);
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        }); 
        
        Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(3);
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        }); 

    }
```

helpppppp

I don't know what else to do, I'm bored of looking for a way, I'm a beginner and I no longer have ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You are Complicating things by using multiple authentication providers, you can instead use the users table for all roles just for authenthication ( users table structure : ID,email,password,role(int),...)

For more profile information you can use the clientes table or cajeros table and use a foreign key for user_id in both tables.

then just add relationship in Users Model to make it easy to load info after authentication.

Now in the login process you simply login all users in same way then redirect them to a role dispatcher where you check for roles using middleware or simple method to send the use to the appropriate route groupes.

I assume you have an architecture problem not a problem with the code.
you can do it using multiple authentication providers but it is just a complication for your use case.

Comment: I did think about doing that, but I wouldn't want to do it that way since I don't want to put clients, cashiers, admin in that same table

Comment: They are not in the same table though. Just the authentication part. The model and their columns are in different table. They would just share the same authentication table/column (email, password, role) then in the other tables(e.g. clients) you can add user_id to form relationship to the client's columns.

Comment: additionally, you would need to add custom attributes to your user model so that you can fetch the info like `Auth::user()->userinfo()`. Inside userinfo attribute, you can do switch statement to fetch which table you want to fetch from. etc.